# Clique em botão funciona no emulador, mas não funciona no celular

Tags: android

Tenho um botão e 2 valores. Quando estou no emulador, tudo funciona que é mil maravilhas..
Já quando exporto a app e a instalo em celular, o mesmo botão não funciona.

```
package br.emanuel.imc;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.ads.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private AdView adView;
Button btCalcular;
EditText etPeso, etAltura, etIdade;
TextView tvResultado, tvCategoria, tvPesoIdeal;//< edit 08/06
double  altura,peso,idade;
double resultado, pesoMin, pesoMax;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btCalcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCalcular);

    etPeso = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPeso);
    etAltura = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAltura);
    etIdade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIdade);

    tvResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResultado);
    tvCategoria = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCategoria);
    tvPesoIdeal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPesoIdeal);

    /*
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app-pub-5576365539424575/7733482150");
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    layout.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    */

    btCalcular.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if((etPeso.getText().length()==0) || (etAltura.getText().length()==0) || (etIdade.getText().length()==0)){
                    Alerta("ATENÇÂO", "Existem campos vazios. Verifique!");
                    return;
                }else{
                    peso = Double.parseDouble(etPeso.getText().toString());
                    altura = Double.parseDouble(etAltura.getText().toString());
                    idade = Double.parseDouble(etIdade.getText().toString());

                    resultado = peso /(altura*altura);
                    resultado = converterDoubleDoisDecimais(resultado);

                    pesoMin = 18.5*(altura*altura);
                    pesoMin= converterDoubleDoisDecimais(pesoMin);

                    pesoMax = 24.99*(altura*altura);
                    pesoMax = converterDoubleDoisDecimais(pesoMax);

                    tvResultado.setText("Resultado: "+resultado);
                    tvPesoIdeal.setText("Peso Ideal: Entre "+pesoMin+" Kgs e "+pesoMax+" Kgs.");
                    if (resultado <17){
                        tvCategoria.setText("Categoria: Muito abaixo do peso.");
                        return;
                        }
                    else{
                        if ((resultado>=17) && (resultado<=18.49)){
                            tvCategoria.setText("Categoria: Abaixo do Peso.");
                            return;
                        }
                        else{
                            if ((resultado>18.49)&& (resultado <=24.99)){
                                tvCategoria.setText("Categoria: Peso Ideal.");
                                return;
                            }
                            else{
                                if((resultado>24.99) && (resultado<=29.99)){
                                    tvCategoria.setText("Categoria: Acima do peso.");
                                    return;
                                }
                                else{
                                    if((resultado>29.99) && (resultado<=34.99)){
                                        tvCategoria.setText("Categoria: Obesidade I.");
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if((resultado>34.99)&&(resultado<39.99)){
                                            tvCategoria.setText("Categoria: Obesidade Severa.");
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            tvCategoria.setText("Categoria: Obesidade Mórbida.");
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            finally{
                etPeso.setText("");
                etAltura.setText("");
                etIdade.setText("");
            }

        }
    });

}

public void Alerta(String titulo, String msg){
    AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alerta.setTitle(titulo);
    alerta.setMessage(msg);
    alerta.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
    alerta.show();
}

public static double converterDoubleDoisDecimais(double valorDouble) {  
    DecimalFormat fr = new DecimalFormat("0.00");        
    String string = fr.format(valorDouble);  
    String[] part = string.split("[.]");  
    String string2 = part[0]+"."+part[1];  
    double valor = Double.parseDouble(string2);  
    return valor;  
}  
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Eu acho que eu deveria usar o `.setOnTouchListener` no lugar do `.setOnClickListener`. Seria essa a solução?

Comment: Poderia postar o `stacktrace` do erro impresso no logcat? Ajuda a saber qual erro e em qual linha o erro ocorreu.

Comment: Acredito que esta ocorrendo algum erro que está sendo silenciado pelo  `catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle exception }`, de um `e.printStackTrace();` dentro do catch e o capture(e o post na pergunta) o erro que está ocorrendo para podermos lhe ajudar.

Comment: @Wakim - Muito Obrigado pela atenção e disposição em ajudar. O problema estava na função de converter para decimal. Especificamente na linha:     String[] part = string.split("[.]"); ... Não me atentei ao separador decimal que é vírgula.

Comment: @Fernando  Idem o comentário acima.

Comment: @emanuelsn ao invés de editar sua pergunta com a resposta, poste uma resposta com a solução, e você mesmo pode aceitar. Isso facilitará na visualização do problema e da solução para outros visitantes do site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido

O problema estava na hora de converter para 2 casas decimais.
Deve-se alterar a linha

```
String[] part = string.split("[.]");
```

do método converterDoubleDoisDecimais para:

```
String[] part = string.split("[,]");
```